# Infrared communication between 2 arduinos

Tags: arduino, infrared

I have 2 arduinos and i want to send from the first arduino, the input of the serial monitor, to the second arduino, using ir leds.

I use something like that:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Enter a word or a phrase:");
}

void loop() 
{
   if (Serial.available() > 0) 
   {
       serialinput = Serial.read();
   }
   /*then i want here to use an irsend to put the serialinput and send it, 
   via ir to the other arduino 
   and see it in the serial monitor of the receiver. */
   // something like this: irsend.sendSony(serialinput, 20)
}
```

So, can you tell me if this would work and which irsend should i use, because i dont know the difference between them? (for example there is a sendSony, sendNEC, send RC5 and many other). 
Or if I can learn their differences from somewhere, because i cant find them.